# Neo4j Aggregation Subtraction Nodes and properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes

I'm starting with Neo4j and using graphs, and I'm trying to get the following:

I have to find the subtraction(difference) between the number of users (each user is a node) and the number of differents names they have. I have 16 nodes, and each one has his own name (name is one of the properties it has), but some of them have the same name (for example the node A has (Name:Amanda,City:Roma) and node B has (Name:Amanda, City:Paris), so I will have less name's count because some of them are repeated.

I have tried this:

```
 match (n) with n, count(n) as c return sum(c)
```

That gives me the number of nodes. And then I tried this

```
 match (n) with n, count(n) as nodeC with n, count( distinct n.Name) as 
 nameC return sum(nodeC) as sumN, sum(nameC) as sumC, sumN-sumC
```

But it doesn't work (I'm not sure if even i'm getting the names well, because when I try it, separated, it doesn't work neither).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN COUNT(n) - COUNT(DISTINCT n.name) AS diff;
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't need to count() and then sum() again, it worked!